# Error protecting Glassfishv3 with J2ee-openam-agent

Tags: web-services, glassfish, openam, javaagents

I am trying to protect a Glassfish v3.0.0 with a J2EE agent (v3.3.0 and OpenAM server v9.5.3).

The installation and deployment was OK, but when I log in with a valid user I get some errors.

I don´t know if it is a compatibility problem, a GlassFish misconfiguration or another thing.

These are the error logs:

**Browser error**

Exceptions details : null

```
________________________________________
java.lang.NullPointerException at java.io.File.(File.java:222) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.initializePort(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:505) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doGet(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:165) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:100) at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doGet(JAXWSServlet.java:193) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215) at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentBaseFilter.allowRequestToContinue(AmAgentBaseFilter.java:128) at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentBaseFilter.doFilter(AmAgentBaseFilter.java:78) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97) at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954) at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88) at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76) at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53) at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57) at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)


**GlassFish Log**


[#|2014-08-05T16:15:29.109+0200|WARNING|glassfishv3.0|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080-(1);|StandardWrapperValve[default]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentFilter
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1985)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:888)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1420)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:245)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]

[#|2014-08-05T16:15:29.109+0200|WARNING|glassfishv3.0|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|StandardWrapperValve[default]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentFilter
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1985)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:888)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1420)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:245)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]
```

***Thanks for your time and tips.***